# Push notification with message counts like android in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, notifications

[image]

Is there any way to implement like this view in ios....if not then please specify why it can't achieve... I am new to this development.....

Answer (score 0):

The badgeNumber can be used to display the count

In objective C ,

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:messageCount]; // 

}
```

In Swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = messagecount
```